robot_localization for a drone
I'm currently programming a drone using Ros2 Humble on a Raspberry Pi and I'm trying to add robot_localisation to it. I only have one IMU (ICM20948) and I want to get as much information as possible about its localisation.
I have already set up the imu and ekf nodes, but the communication between them doesn't work. The imu node works fine.
I don't really know what is missing or not working. Maybe there is a problem with frames, imu data or orientation? How can I debug this?
You can find my codes in my repo:
https://github.com/MatWac/Drone-Pi/tree/main/src/icm_publisher
Thanks for your help!

In your launch file, you have named your ekf package config ekf_filter but it is named ekf_filter_node in the ekf.yaml file. Fix this issue and  I think the ekf node will be able to subscribe to imu data.
Also please don't give the absolute path of your parameter file to ekf node, you can edit setup.py to give the relative path so it would be usable elsewhere.

Okay, I hadn't noticed that. Thank you very much!
